# Database suggestion (and possible readings) for heavy computational website

Tags: database, web, computation

I'm building a website that will rely on heavy computations to make guess and suggestion on objects of objects (considering the user preferences and those of users with similar profiles). Right now I'm using MongoDB for my projects, but I suppose that I'll have to go back to SQL for this one.

Unfortunately my knowledge on the subject is high school level. I know that there are a lot of relational databases, and was wondering about what could have been some of the most appropriate for this kind of heavily dynamic cluster analysis. Also I would really appreciate some suggestion regarding possible readings (would be really nice if free and online, but I won't mind reading a book. Just maybe not a 1k pages one if possible).

Thanks for your help, extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommondations are typically a graph like problem, so you should also consider looking into graph databases, e.g. [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org)

Comment: This looks very interesting indeed. I have never heard about this kind of databases (never the less about this specific one): reading on their website however I cannot quite understand how this architecture could be superior to MySQL or similar relational databases. All the objects that I'm talking about have the same structure, although their evaluation varies greatly as result of individual valuation. This answer discourages me greatly from choosing this kind of database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046442/comparision-of-relational-databases-and-graph-databases . Any idea?

Comment: IMHO the answer you're referring to is due to the lack of knowledge of graph databases. Maybe the webinar/videos on neo4j.org give a good intro.

Comment: I will have to do some further research to understand the subject better, but this is indeed the correct answer to the provided question. Thanks for your help!