# Does GraphQL negate the need for Graph Databases

Tags: neo4j, relational-database, graphql, graph-databases

Most of the [reasons for using a graph database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046442/comparison-of-relational-databases-and-graph-databases) seem to be that relational databases are slow when making graph like queries.

However, if I am using GraphQL with a data loader, all my queries are flattened and combined using the data loader, so you end up making simpler `SELECT * FROM X` type queries instead of doing any heavy joins. I might even be using a No-SQL database which is usually pretty fast at these kinds of flat queries.

If this is the case, is there a use case for Graph databases anymore when combined with GraphQL? Neo4j seems to be [promoting](https://neo4j.com/developer/graphql/) GraphQL. I'd like to understand the advantages if any.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GraphQL doesn't negate the need for graph databases at all, the connection is very powerful and makes GraphQL more performant and powerful.

You mentioned:

> However, if I am using GraphQL with a data loader, all my queries are flattened and combined using the data loader, so you end up making simpler SELECT * FROM X type queries instead of doing any heavy joins.

This is a curious point, because if you do a lot of `SELECT * FROM X` and the data is connected by a graph loader, you're still doing the joins, you're just doing them in software outside of the database, at another layer, by another means.  If even that software layer isn't joining anything, then what you gain by not doing joins in the database you're losing by executing many queries against the database, plus the overhead of the additional layer.  Look into the performance profile of sequencing a series of those individual "easy selects".  By not doing those joins, you may have lost 30 years value of computer science research...rather than letting the RDMBS optimize the query execution path, the software layer above it is forcing a particular path by choosing which selects to execute in which order, at which time.

It stands to reason that if you don't have to go through any layer of formalism transformation (relational -> graph) you're going to be in a better position.  Because that formalism translation is a cost you must pay every time, every query, no exceptions.  This is sort of equivalent to the obvious observation that XML databases are going to be better at executing XPath expressions than relational databases that have some XPath abstraction on top.  The computer science of this is straightforward; purpose-built data structures for the task typically outperform generic data structures adapted to a new task.

I recommend [Jim Webber's article on the motivations for a native graph database](https://www.datanami.com/2017/05/17/motivation-native-graph-databases/) if you want to go deeper on why the storage format and query processing approach matters.

What if it's not a native graph database?  If you have a graph abstraction on top of an RDBMS, and then you use GraphQL to do graph queries against **that**, then you've shifted where and how the graph traversal happens, but you still can't get around the fact that the underlying data structure (tables) isn't optimized for that, and you're incurring extra overhead in translation.

So for all of these reasons, a native graph database + GraphQL is going to be the most performant option, and as a result I'd conclude that GraphQL doesn't make graph databases unnecessary, it's the opposite, it shows where they shine.

They're like chocolate and peanut butter.  Both great, but really fantastic together.  :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes GraphQL allows you to make some kind of graph queries, you can start from one entity, and then explore its neighborhood, and so on.

But, if you need performances in graph queries, you need to have a **native** graph database.

With GraphQL you give a lot of power to the end-user. He can make a deep GraphQL query.

If you have an SQL database, you will have two choices:

- to compute a big SQL query with a lot of joins (really bad idea)
- make a lot of SQL queries to retrieve the neighborhood of the neighborhood, ...

If you have a native graph database, it will be just one query with good performance! It's a graph traversal, and native graph database are made for this.

Moreover, if you use GraphQL, you consider your data model as a graph. So to store it as graph seems obvious and gives you less headache :)

I recommend you to read this post: [The Motivation for Native Graph Databases](https://blog.grandstack.io/five-common-graphql-problems-and-how-neo4j-graphql-aims-to-solve-them-e9a8999c8d43)

---

### Answer for Graph Loader

With Graph loader you will  do a lot of small queries (it's the second choice on my  above answer) but wait no, ... there is a cache record.

Graph loaders just do `batch` and `cache`.

For comparaison:

- you need to add another library and implement the logic (more code)
- you need to manage the cache. There is a lot of documentation about this topic. (more memory and complexity)
- due to `SELECT *` in loaders, you will always get more data than needed Example: I only want the `id` and `name` of a user not his `email`, `birthday`, ... (less performant)
- ...

Comment: If you use a GraphQL data loader, you don't need any joins. It also reduces the number of SQL queries. This is the reason I am asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from FrobberOfBits is very good. There are many reasons to add (or avoid) using GraphQL, whether or not a graph database is involved. I wanted to add a small consideration against putting GraphQL in front of a graph. Of course, this is just one of what ought to be many other considerations involved with making a decision.

If the starting point is a relational database, then GraphQL (in front of that datbase) can provide a lot of flexibility to the caller – great for apps, clients, etc. to interact with data. But in order to do that, GraphQL needs to be aligned closely with the database behind it, and specifically the database schema. The database schema is sort of "projected out" to apps, clients, etc. in GraphQL.

However, if the starting point is a native graph database (Neo4j, etc.) there's a world of schema flexibility available to you because it's a graph. No more database migrations, schema updates, etc. If you have new things to model in the data, just go ahead and do it. This is a really, really powerful aspect of graphs. If you were to put GraphQL in front of a graph database, you also introduce the schema concept – GraphQL needs to be shown what is / isn't allowed in the data. While your graph database would allow you to continue evolving your data model as product needs change and evolve, your GraphQL interactions would need to be updated along the way to "know" about what new things are possible. So there's a cost of less flexibility, and something else to maintain over time.

It might be great to use a graph + GraphQL, or it might be great to just use a graph by itself. Of course, like all things, this is a question of trade-offs.